# How to overwrite a constrains in method read/write odoo

Tags: odoo

At first I have a module A overwrite method write and add a constrains likes this:

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    if 'employee_id' in vals:
        if not self.env['hr.employee'].browse(vals['employee_id']).user_id:
            raise UserError(_('You must link this employee to a user'))
    return super(class_name, self).write(vals)
```

Then I create a module B inherit module A and I want to remove the constraints in write method but no way. I've tried to inherit write method and remove the constrains but no luck, all I can do is replacing constrains string by another sentences but it 's not what I want, how can I resolve it ?

**Update #1**: based on suggestion of @thangtn but it still not working

```
    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        try: 
            if 'employee_id' in vals:
                if not self.env['hr.employee'].browse(vals['employee_id']).user_id:
                    raise UserError(_('You must link this employee to a user'))
        except UserError
            pass
        super(class_name, self).write(vals)
```

**Update #2**: problem is resolved by change `super(class_name, self).write(vals)` to `models.Model.write(self, vals)` in above code (Update #1)

Comment: why not use @api.constrains instead of putting constrains in write methods?

Comment: I don't know, module A is not written by me, all I need is remove this constrains

Answer (score 2):

You could use try/except to bypass the constrains in the original

```
from openerp.exceptions import UserError

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    try:
        super(class_name, self).write(vals)
    except UserError:
        # Your code goes here
        # ...
```

Comment: I 've tried your suggestion but it's not resolve my problem, it pass the constrain I catch but still get the same constrain in parent method , I 've updated in on my ask